# Hey, where'd our "belongs on musicfans" close-reason go?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons

I went to vote to close a question just now as being better suited for musicfans.stackexchange. When I clicked on "A community-specific reason" and "belongs on another site," the only option given was music.meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We never had one. We also cannot have it until the site moves out of beta. Mods can and have done it manually in the past.

In general migration paths can be made from one site to another site as long as the are both fully graduated sites. An overall overview of migration can be found here: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Ok, that’s weird; follow-up question, how did I hallucinate a memory of us having one? Oh well.

Comment: Not totally sure. Questions have been migrated, but only by mods.